# Conditional type when key is defined in object parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to return a different type if an optional key in an object is defined. In the following code I try to explain what I am trying to achieve:

```js
interface Model {
    name: string;
}

interface Arg {
    id?: number;
}

const func = (obj: Arg): Arg["id"] extends number ? Model : Model[] => {
    if (obj.id) {
        return eval(""); // will return Model;
    } else {
        return eval(""); // will return Model[];
    }
}

const all = func({}); // correct `Model[]` inference
const single = func({ id: 1 }); // expected inference `Model`, actually `Model[]`
```

Ignore the `eval` call here, in my actual code this is actually a service that returns `any` as well. What I'd like to have it back from this function is that everytime I pass an `id` to the object as argument, it returns a single `Model` otherwise `Model[]`.

I expected the signature of my method to be correct

```
(obj: Arg): Arg["id"] extends number ? Model : Model[]
```

but that doesn't seem to be working, is there a way to get it back what I am expecting?

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDchAvoYaJLIigCCUZgWKlgmAPy0QAVwoAjaOy6EE6EA2Qw5IBMgC8yABTpFAK1rDmASmsiA2gCJJzgLrIIAD0ghMdGQKylDIUmhYuMi0GNg4jp6GAHxipMjAMKbmFgB0krapaaRQEGByUCBeAG5wOCbOzrasyAD0LcgA7sA4eCVlFRFx7GkcXjh0KERFxaXllRA1dQ1Nre1dPch9c4O4CcOkXGoaWmDItXjGuvom+BwrbcgaUCUIpwAGsbvub+kgMNAQfQQdSabR0Fg4FCXPQIG7pTC0ACMyDuzQePgADhBXhBML9-iUgcgPpEcG8ADRnV5yc4AT2Jn3i30IQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arg["id"]` will always get you `number | undefined`. You have to make the function generic:

```js
const func = <T extends Arg>(obj: T): T["id"] extends number ? Model : Model[] => {
    if (obj.id) {
        return eval(""); // will return Model;
    } else {
        return eval(""); // will return Model[];
    }
}
```

Now `T` refers to the type of the actual argument and not the `Arg` interface.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeAUMiciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDchAvoYaJLIigCCUZgWKlgmAPy0QAVwoAjaOy6EE6EA2Qw5IBMgC8yADwAVZBAAekEJjrJhzAHwAKdIoBWtMwEofANoARJJBALqWNhB2DvJK0MhSaFi4yLQY2DgBEYbOYqTIwDDI7l4AdJK++QWkUBBgclAglgBucDiuQUG+rMgA9H3IAO7AOHh1DU3JmewFHJY4dChENbX1jc0QbR1dPf2DI2PIExvTuNmzpFxqGlpgyO14xrr6rvgcewPIGlB1CPcAAwy5zCAMKIBg0GiSHUmm0dBYOBQzz0CDehUwtAAjMgPr0vtYAA4Qf4QTDgyF1fQoIEpHAAgA0D3+ckeAE9kLTMtkAUA)

Comment: That works, thanks for it. Although I can't seem to understand why a generic extending that interface is not the same as the direct access to the value...

Comment: `Arg` is always the interface, no matter what value you pass to the function. The generic `T` however is the type of the argument value. e.g. `{}` in the first call and `{ id: number }` in the second.